# How to display the title of a component in another component (React.js)?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React project in which I have a `Projects` component that contains a list of individual projects - each project is another component called `Project`. Each `Project` has a title, a description and some buttons. There is a view button that should take to another component called `ProjectPage`, that should display the title of the `Project`. For example, if the title in the `Project` is "This is a test", the title in the `ProjectPage` should be the same.

Here is the code on Github if it helps: https://github.com/George-Florin/time-tracking-app

The data is stored in a db.json file, so the command "npm run server" is necessary for the projects to load.

Comment: Hi George,

You should not send your github repo but paste the revelant code in your issue instead

Comment: I see that ProjectPage component takes a project prop. Does not project prop has title ?

Comment: I don't know. If I try to add {project.title} in a <h1> in the ProjectPage component, I get a "cannot read property "title" of undefined" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have a `MyContext` containing your fetched `projects`.

You also have the selected project `id` in your `ProjectPage` props.

So you just need to get the good project from your context with the id:

```js
const { projects } = useContext(MyContext)
const { params: { id } } = match

const project = projects.find(project => project.id === parseInt(id))
```

In your `Title` component, I see you are getting data from your `Project` component... this is not very good.

You should get data from the props of your component instead.

```js
const Title = ({title, description}) => {
    return (
        <div className="title">
            <h1>Title {title}</h1>
            <h3>{description}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And pass your title in the `Title` like this:

```js
<Title title={project.title} description={project.description} />
```

Or you could give the whole `project` object as a prop too.

---

While the above should work when you are coming from the home page (`http://localhost:3000/`), this won't work if you reload the `http://localhost:3000/projectpage/1` page.

You will get this error:

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

This is because you are fetching data in `Main`. You should fetch data higher in your hierarchy of components. For example in `App` or in `MyContextProvider`. React can be hard when starting

Comment: And where should this be added ?

Comment: This should be added at the start of your `ProjectPage` component.

Comment: Notice the `parseInt()` I added in the `projects.find()` because the `id` you are getting from the url is a string.

Comment: Tried this, but I still get the "cannot read property "title" of undefined " error.

Comment: This should work as long as you are coming from the home page. You should first go to `http://localhost:3000/` **and then** navigate to `http://localhost:3000/projectpage/1`. I'll explain why in my answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated something and it works now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @George I updated my answer as promised. You are welcome and good luck continuing using React!